# How can I set a bean property when the page is loading in jsf?

Tags: jsf, javabeans

In my project, I am using myfaces 1.2, rich faces 3.3.3 and spring 2.5 for backing beans. I searched over Internet for this simple need all weekend but I couldn't managed to set the bean property. h:inputhidden trick is good for calling a bean function. But I couldn't use this to set the property. For instance I want to set a bean property named as "number" to "1" when a page is loading.

Over internet I saw these was being used to set the bean property. I am new in web programming and I don't know how these working.. But maybe these make you remember something.

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
request.getParameter()
<h:inputhidden>
```

**Updated:**
I want to set the value from the page not in bean. so I must get the value from the page. I will set the bean property differently in different pages. and I am using one bean for multiple page.

Comment: what scope does your bean have?

Comment: @Component("myBean")
@Scope("session")

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

- `<f:view before="#{bean.beforePhaseMethod}">` (if using facelets it's called `beforePhase`)
- a `@PostConstruct` method for request-scoped beans
- if there is no logic, simply give an initial value of the field `private int foo = 1`

Comment: I want to set the value from the page not in bean.